# Why doesn't keepalived track_script restart keepalived when HAProxy drops out?

Tags: haproxy, keepalived

UPDATE: seems to need a custom track script to actually failover and restart when HAProxy dies. Posted as answer.

I have keepalived (plus VIP) + haproxy + galera_node (on the same host, config below) setup using the same track script found in dozens of examples around the internet. What I don't get is when I kill the `haproxy` process running on a given node, this is what shows up in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Keepalived_vrrp[29230]: VRRP_Instance(250) Entering MASTER STATE
Keepalived_vrrp[29230]: VRRP_Script(check_haproxy) failed
```

Makes sense. It did fail. But the odd thing is `keepalived` is neither relinquishing the VIP nor entering BACKUP state which is what the desired behavior is (below, VIP is still there several minutes after haproxy left). Am I misunderstanding how `keepalived` is designed to work, or is there some other apparent error in my config? (KA version is 1.2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
# ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:02:c6:83:82:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
    inet 10.10.10.202/24 brd 10.20.18.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.10.250/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*keepalived.conf*

```
global_defs
{
  router_id    mynode
}

vrrp_script check_haproxy
{
   script      "killall -0 haproxy"
   interval    1
   fall        2
   weight      2
}

vrrp_instance 200
{
   virtual_router_id 200
   advert_int   1
   nopreempt
   priority     90
   state        BACKUP
   interface    eth0
   notify       /etc/keepalived/log_status.sh

   virtual_ipaddress
   {
     10.10.10.250 dev   eth0
   }

   track_script
   {
     check_haproxy
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to monitor the `haproxy` service on a single node and restart it on failure?

Comment: It's been awhile, (and this project has since been shelved), but IIRC, when the HAProxy process was killed, the VIP was still sticking to that node. I wanted the VIP to be taken over by one of the other 2 galera nodes. It was like `keepalive` didn't know HAProxy gone so the VIP wouldn't switch. What did solve it (for this specific stack and version anyway) was the script in my answer below.. I should probably accept it so it doesn't show up in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a custom track_script now which fixes this. It restarts keepalived if haproxy isn't running. Seems that keepalived only enters BACKUP mode using the default track script on startup/restart, not while it's running ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
#!/bin/sh
# restart keepalive if haproxy died
pid=`/bin/pidof haproxy`
test -z "$pid" && { service keepalived restart &>/dev/null; exit 1; }
exit 0
```